# Is non-abelian simple group complete?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a non-abelian simple group.
I wonder if $G$ is complete; i.e., $\mathrm{Inn}\,G = \mathrm{Aut}\,G$.

Although I am an elementary learner, I know, just by simple calculation, that $\mathrm{Aut}\,G$ is complete: $\mathrm{Inn}\,\mathrm{Aut}\,G = \mathrm{Aut}\,\mathrm{Aut}\,G$. But, what can I do next?

I found some web sites saying $G$ is complete, so I think it may be true. But I have no idea to show the statement.

Could you give me a proof, or books in which I can find a proof?

Comment: Have you considered the very smallest nonabelian simple group?

Comment: What does your simple calculation look like for $\mathrm{Aut}\,G$ being complete?

Comment: First, $A=\mathrm{Inn}\,G$ is characteristic because, for $\phi\in H=\mathrm{Aut}\,G$, $A\cap\phi(A)$ is normal in $\phi(A)$ and $\phi(A)\cong A\cong G$ is simple. Then, $H$ is complete: let $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}\,H$ and $\sigma\in H$ s.t. $\phi(\pi_g)=\pi_{\sigma(g)}(g\in G)$, where $\pi$ is the conjugate map. (It is possible because $A$ is characteristic.) Let $\psi=\phi\pi_{\sigma^{-1}}$. Since $\pi_\tau\pi_g=\pi_{\tau(g)}$, $\tau^{-1}\psi(\tau)\in Z(A)$; hence $\phi=\pi_\sigma\in\mathrm{Inn}\,H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true; the outer automorphism of a finite simple group is not always trivial, for example the outer autmorphism of $A_n, n\neq 6$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $A_n$ is simple for $n>4$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group#In_finite_groups

Comment: Thank you for giving counterexamples! I will try to see the outer automorphism group of A_n is Z_2.